# Remove duplicates from every tables in db

Tags: sqlite, sql-delete

I have a db with multiple tables. The tables have all the same structure with one column called `date` and a bunch of other columns with various data.

I can remove the duplicates from a single table as follow:

```
DELETE FROM table1
WHERE EXISTS (
    SELECT 1 FROM table1 p2
    WHERE table1.date = p2.date
    AND table1.ROWID > p2.ROWID
)
```

I have about `30 tables` to clean regularly. Although I could run the above code for each table, is there a way to do this via a `for loop` after getting the list of tables in the db as:

```
SELECT name FROM sqlite_master WHERE type='table'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a `PL/SQL block` to achieve this,

Please try with this script:

```
DO $$ 
DECLARE
    table_name text;
BEGIN
    -- Loop through the list of table names
    FOR table_name IN (SELECT name FROM sqlite_master WHERE type='table') LOOP
        -- Generate and execute the DELETE statement for each table
        EXECUTE 'DELETE FROM ' || table_name || ' WHERE EXISTS (
            SELECT 1 FROM ' || table_name || ' p2
            WHERE ' || table_name || '.date = p2.date
            AND ' || table_name || '.ROWID > p2.ROWID
        )';
    END LOOP;
END $$;
```

This block will execute the `DELETE` statement for each table, `removing duplicates` based on the specified criteria.

*Make sure to execute this code within your SQLite environment

Answer (score 2):

Here's a script that generates & runs individual DELETE statements for each table:
--> Loops through the table list and remove duplicates from each table

```
BEGIN;
 FOR table_name IN (SELECT * FROM table_list) DO
   EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'DELETE FROM ' || table_name.name || ' WHERE ROWID NOT IN (
     SELECT MAX(ROWID) FROM ' || table_name.name || ' GROUP BY date
   )';
 END FOR;
COMMIT;
```